# How to use (get and set) httpcontext.current.Session in the class library, within MVC web api application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am getting error as "object reference not set to an instance of an object httpcontext.current.session".

Comment: The field you are trying to check in session does not exist yet.

Comment: I want to use session value throughout the application including class library.

Comment: search "httpcontext.current.session web api" on google. you'll find the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should get knowledge of Session.

Before retrieving HttpContext.Current.Session follow following steps.

1. Set Session Value:

   ```
   HttpContext.Current.Session["ID"] = value;
   ```
2. Get Session Value:

   ```
   var value = HttpContext.Current.Session["ID"];
   ```

Be confirm you have derived System.Web.dll reference in your project Reference

You will get error = `"Object reference not set...."` when key in `Session["ID"]` not matched and this is case sensitive.

Comment: I have done above code. However, i was still facing the same issue. In order to solve the problem, i have added below functions in Global.asax.cs file and the issue was resolved.

public override void Init()
        {
            this.PostAuthenticateRequest += MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest;
            base.Init();
        }

        void MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(
                SessionStateBehavior.Required);
        }